Multiple dynamics routes NextJS
I added translation to my site with next-intl, my folder tree looks like /app/[locale]/
I have also a blog under /[slug], after translation article urls looks like domain.fr/fr/article-name
older url was domaine.fr/article-name. There is a huge SEO loss. I didn't achieve translation and keep my article at domain.fr/article-name
i tried to change my tree
/app 
   /[slug] 
   /localized
        /[locale] 

and add a rewrite in
next.config.js file
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:locale/:path*",
        destination: "/localized/:locale/:path*",
        locale: false, 
      },
      { 
        source: "/:slug",
        destination: "/:slug",
        locale: false,
      },
    ];
  },

My site still working with translation but my article return a 404 erorr at domain.fr/aticle-name
